# replace integer with string (integer with commas) in QSpinBox Widget - PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qspinbox

I used PyQt4 designer to add QSpinBox Widget to my project. the QSpinBox Widget contains an integer number (counter).
I'm updating this number with this `setValue()` method.

I want to replace this integer number with the same number just with commas. so now it will be a string and not integer.

is it possible to add a string (integer with commas) to QSpinBox Widget? if no, what widget should I use? and what are the methods that I should use?
thanks.

Comment: You could show examples of string you want to put, please.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly exactly *why* you want to do this? It seems very strange to display the numbers in quotes (if that's what you really mean) - how would the user benefit from that? Currently, your question has all the hallmarks of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

Just subclass `QSpinbox` and override the [`textFromValue`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#textFromValue) method. You will need to change the range with [`setRange`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#setRange) to be able to see the formatting since the default max value is 99.

```
class CommaSpinBox(QtWidgets.QSpinBox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CommaSpinBox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def textFromValue(self, value):
        return '{:,d}'.format(value)
```